# Hiding Unknown Files in Batch Files

Tags: file, batch-file, directory, hidden-files

Hey guys i need to know how to hide a file of which i dont know the name of.

for instance i have 6 folders named 1-6 but i think that their named a-f. and their directory is C:\users\all users\bond.

how would i go about doing this?

I dont need to hide the directory of which the files are located i need to be able to enter the directory and hide the files within.

here's the only thing i can think of:

```
@echo off
cd C:\users\all users\bond
attrib +h +s %filename% *
echo.
echo files successfully hidden.
pause
exit
```

Comment: So you want to hide a all the files within a given folder?

Comment: yes, i dont want to hide the folder that the files are in but the files inside of the folder itself. so if i have the folder being TEST and the files being 1 2 3 i want to hide 1 2 3 and not hide TEST, but i need to be able to do it with only knowing that the folders name is TEST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over the folders.

The `for` command can takes a list of folder names or wildcards.

```
@echo off
cd /d c:\users\all users\bond
for /d %%D in (FOLDER NAMES GO HERE) do (
    pushd %%D
    attrib +h *.*
    popd
    )
exit /b
```

If you need to process *all* the folders in the current directory, just put `*` there:

```
...
for /d %%D in (*) do (
...
```

You could also *not* change to the parent directory but specify it in the `for` loop instead (note the quotes around the mask):

```
@echo off
for /d %%D in ("c:\users\all users\bond\*") do (
...
```

Similarly, you could omit jumping in to and out of each subdirectory and instead specify the path in the `attrib` command.

So, the above script could be rewritten like this:

```
@echo off
for /d %%D in ("c:\users\all users\bond\*") do attrib +h "%%D\*"
exit /b
```

Comment: I took the liberty of adding my suggestions on "enhancing" the script to your post. Please feel free to roll them back if necessary or edit them as you see fit.